# UVa_100 3n+1, I got wrong answer

Tags: c++

here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

long long int problem(long long int);
int counter = 0;

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    while(cin >> i >> j){

        int max = 0;
        if(i > j){

            int temp = i;
            i = j;
            j = temp;
        }
        for(long long int count = i; count <= j; count++){

            counter = 1;
            problem(count);
            if(counter > max) max = counter;
        }

        cout << i << " " << j << " " << max << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
long long int problem(long long int n)
{
    if(n == 1){

    }
    else
    {
        if(n % 2 == 1){
            counter++;
            return problem(3 * n+1);
        }else{
            counter++;
            return problem(n/2);
        }
    }

}
```

I tried every input provided by UVa and get the correct output,
however, UVa still return me with "Wrong Answer".

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the input? What is the output (expected and actual)?

Comment: here it is
http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=36

Sample Input

1 10
100 200
201 210
900 1000
Sample Output

1 10 20
100 200 125
201 210 89
900 1000 174

Comment: My actual output are all the same as expected

Comment: For starters, what do you think will happen if `n == 1` in the `problem` function? Not that you actually *use* the result from the function, but you should still think about it. You should also listen to the warnings the compiler may give you, and if it doesn't give you warnings then you should turn on more warnings.

Comment: so should I return 1 for  n==1 ?

Comment: huge thanks for your help, especially to a beginner

Answer (score 1):

Your program is okay.
Just print the numbers as they appeared in input. That is :

Input : `10 5`

Correct Output : `10 5 20`

Your Output : `5 10 20`

Comment: @AdrianHsu welcome :)
It would be great if you accept the answer